# Is it possible to combine active and passive gems of different colors?

Tags: path-of-exile

I'd like to combine [Item Rarity (passive blue)](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Item_Rarity) with my AoE [Rain of Arrows (active green)](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Rain_of_Arrows).  Of course I can socket these gems the way I want, but will the Rain of Arrows benefit of the Item Rarity's boost ?

Comment: Arc (Active blue) + Chain (support green) increases the number of times it jumps dramatically; wouldn't make sense to limit supports to only those of the same color.  Spell Totem, especially, would lose much of it's effectiveness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"**Yes**", you can. That's why different colors tend to be linked at all.

The only thing that wont work is bad mechanics logic (Multiple Projectiles/Fork and Glacial Hammer for example, do not work together that well).

Comment: Ok ok; I understood the second part for PoE's documentation (website and wiki), but wasn't sure about the first part.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problems at all! Heh, I found this out by lurking the Yolo league global chat.

Comment: The...  WHAT league ?!  What the hell is that ?

Comment: Sounds like Hardcore league; you only live once, ie. Hardcore.

Comment: Yeah ok, I know the *hardcore* league. But *yolo*... ?!

Comment: @Anto Well, it **is** [using the term properly](http://www.virtualshackles.com/343).

Comment: Omg, [it's an acronym](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/yolo).  Never heard of it before.  Ok, thanks.